# Django atomic boolean

Tags: django

Does anybody know how to read/write an atomic Booleanfield in Django? I'm trying to do the following:

I've a field in a model called email_sent. Whenever I get a instant payment notification (IPN) from our payment processor I want to send a notification email. Since I get multiple notifications, and I just want to sent 1 receipt email, I (for now) simply use a check in the model whether or not a receipt email has already been sent or not. Sometimes however, I get multiple IPN's at the same time for the same user. I don't want to sent multiple emails, but the following code introduces a race condition:

```
if purchase.email_sent:
    self.send_email()
    purchase.email_sent = True
purchase.save()
```

This is clearly not the right approach, but how do you implement an atomic read/write on a boolean field (postgresql)? I realize there are 2 approaches to solving this:
1) use a counter and do an update()
2) use an atomic memcached operation

Both 1 and 2 seem ugly hacks that shouldn't be necessary. Any thoughts and/or am I missing something obvious?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do not send notifications instantly. Queue all notifications and send them using a background process.

Comment: Not bad, but this is a workaround and doesn't answer the question directly.  I also wonder if this functionality exists, although I'm not sure the concept of an "atomic" variable is applicable in an interpreted language.

Comment: @Justin Myles Holmes: any other solution would involve some kind of shared lock, which are potentialy dangerous and less elegant than my advice. If something looks too hard in Django, probably you are in the wrong path.

Comment: Good idea Paulo, thanks! I still wonder though: it's possible to atomically increment a counter in the db, so why not read/toggle a boolean? It doesn't seem to be a very esoteric use case.

Comment: @Dick: PostgreSQL provides various lock modes to control concurrent access to data in tables. These modes can be used for application-controlled locking in situations where MVCC does not give the desired behavior. IMHO not worth in this case.